# How to validate a JSON with jq?

Tags: bash, jq

I'm writing a bash library where I need to read a JSON file that contains user input; the JSON won't be forged but it might contain armful values for bash scripts, depending on how the form was validated upstream.

In the function that loads the JSON into a bash array, I'm not aware of the keys that must exist yet; still, there are some rules that I would like to enforce here:

1. The JSON must contain a single object
2. All keys shall be named like shell variables
3. All values must be scalars
4. No `NUL` byte in values

```json
{
  "": "empty key shall fail",
  "illegal key shall fail": "keys shall follow the naming convention of shell variables",
  "non_scalar_shall_fail_1": [1,2],
  "non_scalar_shall_fail_2": {"k":"v"},
  "nul_byte_shall_fail": "file.php\u0000.txt"
}
{
  "task_uuid": "5d7ea654-b649-452b-a8fd-002b56be9a59",
  "task_name": "hello world",
  "user_email": null,
  "min": 7,
  "max": 100,
  "ave": 2.5,
  "file_in": "data.txt",
  "file_out": "results.txt"
}
```

I can enforce **#2** and **#4** but I don't know how to do it for **#1** and **#3**:

```bash
jq -r '
    to_entries[] |
    if (.key | test("\\A[_a-zA-Z]\\w*\\z") | not)
    then
        ("error: illegal key " + (.key | tojson) + "\n" |
        halt_error(1))
    else
        if (.value | tostring | test("\u0000"))
        then
            ("error: NUL byte in value " + (.value | tojson) + "\n" |
            halt_error(1))
        else
            # dummy output
            .key + "=" + (.value | @sh)
        end
    end
'
```

The result is quite unexpected: the `halt_error` half-works and I get a coredump...

```
error: illegal key ""
task_uuid='5d7ea654-b649-452b-a8fd-002b56be9a59'
task_name='hello world'
user_email=null
min=7
max=100
ave=2.5
file_in='data.txt'
file_out='results.txt'
*** Error in `jq': corrupted double-linked list ***
...
Aborted                 (core dumped)
```

Is it even possible to do all those validations with `jq` or do I need to switch to an other tool?

Comment: Is your JSON as simple as your example? Or can it contain nested objects etc?

Comment: @0stone0 No nested objects/arrays: I need to validate that the input is a single JSON object and that the values are all scalars.

Comment: [off-topic] Did you consider using a JSON schema for the above? Also it depends on where the validation is required. IMO, jq isn't supposed to solve this problem. You need to find the right toolset for the job

Comment: @Inian I might be able to enforce further validations where the JSON is generated, but I'll still need to read the parameters in bash eventually; I would like to prevent obviously harmful things when doing so.

Comment: For #1, did you try something like `arr=( $(jq -s '.[] | length' < foo.json) )` and then `[[ ${#arr[@]} == 1 ]] || echo one-object-error`?

Comment: And for #2 a staring point could be something like: `jq '.[] | select(type=="array" or type=="object") | length' < foo.json`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, JQ can do all that. Here is how I'd write it:

```
jq -nr '
def valid_key: test("^[A-Za-z_][0-9A-Za-z_]*$");
def valid_value:
    type != "array" and type != "object" and (
        type != "string" or (test("\u0000") | not)
    );
def valid_input:
    type == "object" and (
        to_entries | all(
            (.key | valid_key) and (.value | valid_value)
        )
    );
input |
    if valid_input and isempty(inputs) then
        to_entries[] | "\(.key)=\(.value | @sh)"
    else
        "bad input\n" | halt_error(1)
    end'
```

Comment: Thank you @oguzismail, the code is very easy to understand; now I'll try to make it more verbose about the type of error.

Comment: I made it verbose using `// error(...)` in the `valid_*` functions

Answer (score 2):

Here's a demo how to do the testing. For production, however, it'd obviously need more refinement.

```bash
if type != "object" then "\(@json) is not an object (#1)"
else to_entries[] |
  if .key | test("\\A[_a-zA-Z]\\w*\\z") | not then "\(.key | @json) is illegal (#2)"
  else .value |
    if isempty(scalars) then "\(.) is not a scalar (#3)"
    else tostring |
      if test("\u0000") then "\(.[index("\u0000")+1:] | @json) is preceded by NUL (#4)"
      else empty
      end
    end
  end
end // (to_entries[] | .key + "=" + (.value | @sh))
```

```
"" is illegal (#2)
"illegal key shall fail" is illegal (#2)
[1,2] is not a scalar (#3)
{"k":"v"} is not a scalar (#3)
".txt" is preceded by NUL (#4)
task_uuid='5d7ea654-b649-452b-a8fd-002b56be9a59'
task_name='hello world'
user_email=null
min=7
max=100
ave=2.5
file_in='data.txt'
file_out='results.txt'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/vxIUfvTdgMW)

Comment: Thank you @pmf, `isempty(scalars)` is a great method for testing that a value is a scalar.

Answer (score 2):

The following is a variant of @oguzismail's answer.  The main difference is that the "driver" program identifies all validation errors in the input, so long as it is a valid stream of JSON entities.

Assuming 1.json and 2.json are the files corresponding to the two sample JSON objects in the Q:

```
(cat 1.json 2.json 1.json1) | jq -n '

# If cond is falsey, then (msg|debug); in all cases, emit .
def verify(cond; msg): 
  . as $in
  | if cond then . else (msg | debug) | $in end;

def valid_key: test("^[A-Za-z_][0-9A-Za-z_]*$");

def valid_value:
  type != "array" and 
  type != "object" and
  (type != "string" or (test("\u0000") | not) );

# $count is for the messages and for the return value
def validate($count):
   if type == "object"
   then to_entries[]
   | verify(.key | valid_key; "invalid key in entity #\($count): \(.key)")
   | verify(.value | valid_value; "invalid value in entity #\($count): \(.value)")
   else "entity #\($count) is not a JSON object" | debug
   end
   | $count;

reduce inputs as $in (0;
  .+1
  | . as $count
  | $in | validate($count) )
| verify(.==1; "only one entity is allowed")
| empty
'
```

produces:

```
["DEBUG:","invalid key in entity #1: "]
["DEBUG:","invalid key in entity #1: illegal key shall fail"]
["DEBUG:","invalid value in entity #1: [1,2]"]
["DEBUG:","invalid value in entity #1: {\"k\":\"v\"}"]
["DEBUG:","invalid value in entity #1: file.php\u0000.txt"]
["DEBUG:","invalid key in entity #3: "]
["DEBUG:","invalid key in entity #3: illegal key shall fail"]
["DEBUG:","invalid value in entity #3: [1,2]"]
["DEBUG:","invalid value in entity #3: {\"k\":\"v\"}"]
["DEBUG:","invalid value in entity #3: file.php\u0000.txt"]
["DEBUG:","only one entity is allowed"]
```

Comment: Thank you @peak, the code is well structured and clean +1. There's a little problem though: valid entries can contain boolean values. Well, it's my fault for not specifying it in the question.